# Review my JavaScript cookie library

Tags: javascript, library

I wrote a small JavaScript libary that aims to simplify JavaScript cookies. You can find the code on Github: 
https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js
I tested it in various browsers and it seems to work everywhere.

It's not a lot of code so I'll insert it here as well:
*I updated the code quite a bit so I posted the new version below.*

```
(function (undefined) {

   var isArray = Array.isArray || function (value) { // check if value is an array created with [] or new Array
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
   },

   isPlainObj = function (value) { // check if value is an object that was created with {} or new Object
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]';
   },

   getKeys = Object.keys || function (obj) { // Object.keys polyfill
      var keys = [],
          key = '';
      for (key in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) keys.push(key);
      }
      return keys;
   },

   retrieve = function (value, fallback) { // return fallback if the value is undefined, otherwise return value
      return value === undefined ? fallback : value;
   },

   _cookie = {

      set: function (key, value, options) {

         if (isPlainObj(key)) {
            for (var k in key) {
               if (key.hasOwnProperty(k)) this.set(k, key[k]);
            }

         } else {

            options = options || {};
            var expires = options.expires || '',
               expiresType = typeof(expires),
               path = options.path ? ';path=' + options.path : '',
               domain = options.domain ? ';domain=' + options.domain : '',
               secure = options.secure ? ';secure' : '';
            if (expiresType === 'string' && expires !== '') expires = ';expires=' + expires;
            else if (expiresType == 'number') { // this is needed because IE does not support max-age
               var d = new Date;
               d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires);
               expires = ';expires=' + d.toGMTString();
            } else if (expires.hasOwnProperty('toGMTString')) expires = ';expires=' + expires.toGMTString();

            document.cookie = key + '=' + escape(value) + expires + path + domain + secure;

         }

         return this; // return the _cookie object to allow chaining

      },

      remove: function (keys) {

         keys = isArray(keys) ? keys : arguments;
         for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
            this.set(keys[i], '', {
               expires: -60 * 60 * 24
            });
         }

         return this; // return the _cookie object to allow chaining

      },

      empty: function () {

         return this.remove(getKeys(this.all())); // return the _cookie object to allow chaining

      },

      get: function (key, fallback) {

         fallback = fallback || undefined;

         if (isArray(key)) {

            var result = {},
               cookies = this.all();

            for (var i = 0, l = key.length; i < l; i++) {
               var value = key[i];
               result[value] = retrieve(cookies[value], fallback);
            }

            return result;


         } else {

            var cookies = this.all();
            return retrieve(cookies[key], fallback);

         }

      },

      all: function () {

         if (document.cookie == '') return {};

         var match = document.cookie.split('; '),
            results = {};
         for (var i = 0, l = match.length; i < l; i++) {
            var tmp = match[i].split('=');
            results[tmp[0]] = unescape(tmp[1]);
         }

         return results;

      },

      enabled: function () {

         var ret = cookie.set('a', 'b').get('a') === 'b';
         cookie.remove('a');
         return ret;

      }

   },

   cookie = function (key, fallback) {
      return _cookie.get(key, fallback);
   },

   methods = ['set', 'remove', 'empty', 'get', 'all', 'enabled'];

   for (var i = 0, l = methods.length; i < l; i++) { // copy all _cookie methods to cookie
      var method = methods[i];
      cookie[method] = _cookie[method];
   }

   window.cookie = cookie;

}());
```

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js/blob/master/readme.md

I would love to know how I can improve the code or the API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass on the `options` argument and filter with `hasOwnProperty()` so inside of the `.set()` method this:

```
     if (isPlainObj(key)) {
        for (var k in key) {
           this.set(k, key[k]);
        }
     }
```

becomes this:

```
     if (isPlainObj(key)) {
        for (var k in key) {
           if (key.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
               this.set(k, key[k], options);
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(key, k)`; otherwise you have unexpected behavior if your data contains a `hasOwnProperty` property.

Comment: @KevinReid - if an object has its own override property called `hasOwnProperty`, then it would seem that it intends to override it.  If we always followed your suggestion, we'd never use a native method of an object, we'd always refer to everything from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: I prefer to distinguish between objects-as-data-structures (which this is intending to be as it doesn't read inherited properties etc.) and objects-as-OO with methods and properties, where inheritance is not rejected.

Comment: @KevinReid - But, JS doesn't have data only objects.  An object is an object and every object has methods which one should be free to use.  I understand the point you're making, but I don't think that's the way JS was designed to be use.  You are free to use it that way yourself, I guess.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with you. BTW I fixed this with the latest update on github. :) https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js/blob/master/cookie.js